# Python - generate exe-file with a other py-script?

Tags: python, exe

I have a *script.py*, where I generate some other python-code which I want to build to a exe-file from within my *sctipt.py*.

Is that possible? How could I get this managed?

Comment: Would saving the code as a py file then using a shell command with pyinstaller to make the exe work?

Comment: @duckboycool unfortunately not. the idea is to have a exe-file that generates a second exe-file on any system.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which operating system you are using, you could just use the subprocess module and call a commandline tool which ceates an exe file from the code you generated.

(You should be running windows to compile the exe successfully)

Comment: but doesn't this require that other stuff,pyinstaller e.g., is running on the machine that is executing my `script.py`? because it needs to be completely independent.

Comment: Compiling a file from source code to binary is very dependent, not only from programs like pyinstaller. pyinstaller is also dependent on the operating system. So you will need to have an open operating system which allows you to do this stuff. Or else you should be running a virtual windows machine inside of your python script. But I don't think that is possible. 

Good luck :)

Comment: are there other ways to execute python-file on any system (i mean hosts without having python installed) ?